# Reading XML files without libraries

Tags: c++, xml

I have an assignment to validate and read contents from a xml file. I've done a parser and validated the file by copying it into a string and reading it, that works by iterating through the string and saving the tags. My problem is when I try to get the content between the tags the code just crashes. Here is some code:

```
    bool validate_tags() {
        string tag;
        for (string::iterator it = text_.begin(); it != text_.end(); it++) {
            if (*it == '<') {
                tag.clear();
                ++it;  // get out of '<'
                if (*it == '/') {
                    ++it;
                    while (*it != '>' && it != text_.end()) {
                        tag += *it;
                        ++it;
                    }
                    string abre = stack.pop();
                    if (tag.compare(abre) != 0) return false;
                } else {
                    while (*it != '>' && it != text_.end()) {
                        tag += *it;
                        ++it;
                    }
                    stack.push(tag);  // pushes tag into a stack
                    string content;
                    if (tag.compare("tag_Im_searching_for") == 0) { // code breaks here
                        while (*it != '<') {
                            content += *it;
                            ++it;
                        }
                        content_queue.enqueue(content);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return stack.empty();
```

The code just throws a std::out_of_range in the loop, even though its not at the end of the string

Comment: `while (*it != '>' && it != text_.end())` You want to check for end-of-text first, *before* dereferencing the invalid iterator. It's kind of pointless to check for `it != text_.end()` after you've already dereferenced it and triggered undefined behavior.

Comment: The body of the loop may consume the complete string and leave `it == text_.end()`. Then `it++` in the `for` statement is executed, which exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: It's not wrong but

    `if (tag.compare(abre) != 0)`

is better written as the easier to understand

    `if (tag != abre)`. Similarly `if (tag.compare("tag_Im_searching_for") == 0)` should be `if (tag == "tag_Im_searching_for")`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Is that worth an answer, or should we VTC as typo?

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik it was the order of the expressions with other problems on the code that I didn't put here.